# Parsing string with 3 hyphens C#

Tags: c#

I have string COO70-123456789-12345-1. I need to parse based on the "-" not the length of the substrings and use the parsed values. I have tried using Regular expressions but having issues.Please suggest.
Also after I have split the values I need to use each values: string A = COO70, int B = 123456789, int C = 12345, short D = 1 . How do I get it in different variables A,B,C,D.

```
string[] results = UniqueId.Split('-');

string A = results[0];
string B = results[1];
string C = results[2];
int k_id = Convert.ToInt32(k_id);
string D = results[3];
short seq = Convert.ToInt16(seq);
```

Comment: What you mean by "parse" ? What exactly you want from the string?

Comment: what issues do you have?

Comment: Do you mean `split`?

Comment: I think he means split

Comment: after I have split the values I need to use each values: string A = COO70, int B = 123456789, int C = 12345, short D = 1

Comment: Maybe put some code examples of what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "COO70-123456789-12345-1";
string[] split = s.Split('-'); //=> {"COO70", "123456789", "12345", "1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf

To find everything before the first hyphen use:

```
string original= "COO70-123456789-12345-1";
string toFirstHyphen=original.Substring(0,original.IndexOf("-"));
```

Or if you want every section use split like the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether the input is formatted as you want and then split to get the parts.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?x)^(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)$";
        Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
        string test = "word-6798-3401-001";

        if((reg.Match(test).Success))
            foreach (var x in test.Split(new char[] {'-'}))
                Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you first want to  split it, but then store it into your values.

I would do something like this:

```
var myString = "COO70-123456789-12345-1";
var stringSet = myString.Split("-"); // This returns an array of values.
```

Now we need to verify that we receive only 4 sub strings:

```
if (stringSet.Count != 4)
    throw Exception e; // Throw a real exception, not this
```

From here we need to know what order our strings should be in and assign them:

```
var A = stringSet[0];
var B = stringSet[1];
var C = stringSet[2];
var D = stringSet[3];
```

While this should answer your question as posed, I would recommend you work with `stringSet` differently personally.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was trying to do, can you pls share you rrecommendation

Comment: I would probably just use stringSet[0], stringSet[1], etc directly so I don't need to create a bunch of new variables. Its more of a preference kind of thing. Yours provides more readability at a slightly higher storage cost.